# ¿Como puedo evitar que se repitan los mismos botones?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con Python, usando la librería gráfica [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter).

#### Pregunta

Creo un botón con [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) y lo ligo a una función que me despliega 3 botones más. Si vuelvo a presionar el mismo botón, están los 3 botones y se repiten los 3 botones para dar un total de 6 botones.

¿Y cómo puedo saber si el botón fue presionado, creí que era con `status` pero veo que no?

Esto es lo que comento:

[image: Se crean 6 botones]

#### Código

(todavía le faltan varias cosas que aún no sé como haré, por ejemplo hacer un sorteo)

```
### Domino Center
### Autor: Enrique Jesus Mora Nieves
### Estado: En desarrollo
import tkinter as tk
from math import *
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.Interfaz()

    def Interfaz(self):
        """El objetivo de la funcion Interfaz, es la de contener los botones 
        principales de la aplicacion, sin embargo planeo cambiar esto por otra 
        forma, mientras trabajare con esto.
        """
        ########################################################      
        #####################logo###############################
        self.logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="img/2.png")
        etiquetalogo = tk.Label(self,
                            image= self.logo).pack()
        ####################Titulo Modalidad####################
        self.modalidad = tk.Label(self,
                                  text="Modalidad",
                                  fg="red",).pack(side="top",
                                                  pady=10,
                                                  padx=20)
        ############Boton Individual#############################
        self.boton_individual = tk.Button(self,
                                          text="Individual",
                                          command=self.Individual,
                                          relief="flat",
                                          overrelief="raised").pack(side="left",
                                                                    pady=10,
                                                                    padx=20)
        ##############Boton Pareja###############################
        self.boton_pareja = tk.Button(self,
                                      text="Pareja",
                                      command=None,
                                      relief="flat",
                                      overrelief="raised").pack(side="left",
                                                                pady=10,
                                                                padx=20)
        ##############Boton Equipo################################
        self.boton_equipo = tk.Button(self,
                                      text="Equipo",
                                      command=None,
                                      relief="flat",
                                      overrelief="raised").pack(side="left",
                                                                pady=10,
                                                                padx=20)
        ##############Boton Sorteo################################
        self.boton_sorteo = tk.Button(self,
                                      text="Sorteo",
                                      command=None,
                                      relief="flat",
                                      overrelief="raised").pack(side="left",
                                                                pady=10,
                                                                padx=20)
        ##################################################################

    def Individual(self):
        """La funcion Individual, Es para pedir al usuario la cantidad de 
        personas que van a participar en la modalidad Individual, datos 
        requeridos para la funcion "Distribucion" y la funcion "Sorteo"
        """
        ####################################################################
        #########Titulo: "Introduzca el numero de personas (Minimo 4)######
        self.titulo_numero_de_personas= tk.Label(self,
                                             text="Introduzca el \n numero de personas (minimo 4)").pack()
        #########Input de tipo INT, inicializado a 4 que es lo minimo, no quise usar condicionales en este caso######
        self.IntVar_individual = tk.IntVar()
        self.IntVar_individual.set(4)
        self.numero_de_personas = tk.Entry(self,
                                       textvariable=self.IntVar_individual,
                                       width=4,
                                       relief="flat").pack()
        #########Listbox para servir como salida#############################
        self.lst_individual = tk.Listbox(self,
                                         width=50,
                                         height = 5,
                                         relief="raised")
        self.lst_individual.pack()
        #########Boton: Distribucion#########################################
        self.boton_distribucion= tk.Button(self,
                                           text="Calcular Distribucion",
                                           fg='white',
                                           command=self.Distribucion)
        self.boton_distribucion.config({'background': '#000'})
        self.boton_distribucion.pack(side="left",
                                     padx=20,
                                     pady=10)
        ############Boton: Limpiar############################################
        self.boton_limpiar = tk.Button(self,
                                       text= "Limpiar pantalla",
                                       fg="white",
                                       command=self.Limpiar)
        self.boton_limpiar.config({"background":"#000"})
        self.boton_limpiar.pack(side="right",
                                padx=20,
                                pady=10)
        ##########Boton: Siguiente############################################
        self.boton_siguiente = tk.Button(self,
                                         text="Siguiente",
                                         fg="white",
                                         command=None)
        self.boton_siguiente.config({"background":"#000"})
        self.boton_siguiente.pack(side="right",
                                  padx=20,
                                  pady=10)
        #######################################################################
    def Distribucion(self):
        """La funcion Distribucion, tiene como objetivo determinar la 
        cantidad de mesas que se van a necesitar en base a la cantidad de 
        personas que se han introducido anteriormente, y indicar cuantas 
        personas deben esperar (1, 2 o 3), de esta manera se facilita al 
        organizador la tarea de calcular la cantidad de mesas y cuantas 
        personas quedan en espera (algo simple, pero bueno, hay que 
        facilitar las cosas xD)
        
        En una mesa solo pueden haber 4, para calcular cuantas mesas hay 
        disponibles, se debe dividir entre 4 si el organizador introduce un 
        numero que no vaya de 4 en 4, la variable quedaria con un valor decimal
        se utiliza la funcion trunc() para eliminar ese decimal y dejar la 
        variable con un numero entero
        
        self.resto_mesas, tiene 4 resultados posibles (0, 0.25, 0.50 y 0.75) 
        esta variable es para determinar si quedan personas por fuera, es decir 
        personas que deben esperar, 0 = 0, 0.25 = 1, 0.50 = 2 y 0.75 = 3
        """

        ######variable que toma el valor de un IntVar() que se pide mediante un .get()#################
        self.n_personas = self.IntVar_individual.get()
        
        self.mesas = trunc(self.n_personas/4)###Mesas necesarias para el numero de personas/4
        
        self.resto_mesas = (self.n_personas/4)-self.mesas
        if self.resto_mesas == self.resto_mesas:
            if self.resto_mesas == 0.25:
                self.personas_extras = 1
            elif self.resto_mesas == 0.50:
                self.personas_extras = 2
            elif self.resto_mesas == 0.75:
                self.personas_extras = 3
        ### En este bloque de codigo se le muesta al usuario la distribucion de las mesas y cuantas personas
        ### extras hay, mediante un insert() en la lista self.lst_individual
        if self.resto_mesas>0 and self.resto_mesas<1:
            self.n_personas = self.n_personas-self.personas_extras
            texto = "Cantidad de mesas disponibles: %d, para las %d personas" %(self.mesas,self.n_personas)
            texto2 = "Y hay %d personas esperando" % (self.personas_extras)
            self.lst_individual.insert(tk.END, texto, texto2)
        else:
            texto = "Cantidad de mesas disponibles %d para las %d personas" %(self.mesas,self.n_personas)
            self.lst_individual.insert(tk.END,texto)
    
    def Limpiar(self):
        """La funcion Limpiar, Borra la informacion contenida en los indices de 
        la lista self.lst_individual
        """    
        self.lst_individual.delete(0,tk.END)

myapp = App()
myapp.master.title("Domino Center")
myapp = tk.mainloop()
```

Disculpen que no termine de identarlo, stackoverflow, por lo que veo no permite el uso del tabulador y bueno alinear todo esas lineas de codigo es algo tardio, idente las que pude sorry.

Comment: No hay una pregunta clara y, por tanto, no hay una respuesta directa. Léete la [guía de uso del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer cómo funciona.

Comment: bueno, aqui va una pregunta clara, creo un boton con tkinter y lo ligo a una funcion que me despliegue 3 botones mas, si vuelvo a presionarel mismo boton, estan los 3 botones y se repiten los 3 botones para dar un total de 6 botones, esto es lo que comento https://k60.kn3.net/6/B/D/C/2/5/F57.jpg y https://k61.kn3.net/0/A/5/9/6/8/D77.jpg

Comment: En lugar de escribir una pregunta concreta en un comentario (ese no es su sitio) reescribe la pregunta de forma que en este hilo solo haya una sola pregunta. Esto permite que otros puedan encontrar un problema concreto de forma más sencilla y, si está respondida de forma satisfactoria, puedan encontrar también la respuesta. También deberías reescribir el título, 'Ayuda con tkinter* no es un título muy descriptivo. Quizá podrías poner '¿Cómo actualizo de forma dinámica un layout con tkinter?' o algo por el estilo. Incluye un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca tu problema concreto.

Comment: @EnriqueMora Agregué lo que comentaste, simplificando un poco la redacción. Por favor fijate si está bien y creo que aún deberías [edit] la pregunta para que quede un poco más clara. En vez de pegar todo el código, tratá de que sea lo mínimo indispensable para poder reproducirlo. Lee [mcve]

Comment: @EnriqueMora Por cierto, para pegar código, pegalo tal cual lo tengas, seleccionalo todo y luego click en el botón `{ }`.

Comment: @EnriqueMora Gracias por rehacer la pregunta. Ello ayuda a que el sitio sea más útil para todos. El código que muestras no aporta un ejemplo mínimo verificable, de hecho, tal cual está no es correcto y no se puede ejecutar. Yo he indentado parte del código pero no sé si expresa realmente lo que querías. Por otra parte, como no incluyes el módulo `modulos` no es posible ejecutar el ejemplo. Unas cuantas cosas: 1) Para nombrar a las funciones/métodos se usa la notación *snake_case*. 2) Los *docstrings* se meten dentro del cuerpo de la función, estás usando *docstrings* de forma aleatoria. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] 3) Algunos *docstrings deberían ser comentarios y los comentarios deberían, por norma general, ser cortos. 4) Las funciones dentro de clases se denominan métodos. 5) normalmente, la longitud de las líneas de código debería ser de 79 caracteres. Muchas de estas cosas están recogidas en el [PEP8](http://pep8.org/). El PEP8 son una serie de convenciones para tener un código 'estandarizado' y poder entender el código de los demás. Miran la respuesta de @Zanzag ya que creo te puede dar una pista sobre cómo seguir.

Comment: @Mariano y @kikocorreoso, ya elimine la linea de codigo que importaba un modulo que no tenia nada, elimine el metodo funcion que por ahora da error y no tiene nada que ver con lo que pregunto en este momento, ya despues publicare una pregunta al respecto de ese metodo, todavia sigo sin saber como evitar que se repitan los botones, yo me imagino que es con el metodo `destroy()` pero sigo sin poder saber si fue presionado o no el boton, requiero saber eso para poder usar el destroy apropiadamente

Answer (score 2):

¿Por qué no crear un valor booleano que se haga True al presionar? Con añadir un If en el botón, ya podrías comprobar si es necesario crear los botones extra o no.

Comment: pero como se si fue presionado, osea puedo crear esa variable booleana, pero aun no se como saber, si el boton no se a presionado o ya fue presionado, que metodo tiene Button para saber si fue presionado el boton, yo creia que era status, pero veo que no es asi

Comment: @EnriqueMora El botón tan sólo lanza el método indicado cuando se pulsa. Es tu código el que tiene que saber controlar si se ha pulsado o no el botón. Opciones: añadir un atributo de control de estado, desactivar botones para que no vuelvan a ser pulsados, etc.

Comment: @ChemaCortes me puedes dar un ejemplo? ya que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Como ejemplo, poniendo al empezar el método `Individual` la línea `self.boton_individual.state = tk.DISABLE`. Decide tú mismo dónde y cuándo debería volver a activarse el botón.